# Japanese complete answer

Tags: grammar

I've just started my journey through Tobira and I would like to know how to make a native style answer, like what conjunctions do they usually use. For example, how would you answer this in Japanese:

> "Where would you like to go in Japan? Why?" (more than 1 place).

The main problem that I'm having is whether I should use the reason first or after I mention the place.

For example is this the best way to answer it:

> アニメが好きですから大阪に行きたいです。それと街が知りたいですから東京にいきたいです。

Should I use that order using から or should I use something like:

> 東京に行きたいです。それは街が知りたいですから。

I would like to know which one sounds more natural? Or is there another way to answer it, that sounds more natural?

Thanks, Nickzus

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. To get the most helpful answer please write the sentence(s) you want to say in English and provide your best attempt at a Japanese equivalent. Explain what particular grammar point you are having trouble with and why.

Comment: For example is this the best way to answer it: "アニメが好きですから大阪に行きたいです。それと街が知りたいですから東京にいきたいです"? Should I use that order using から　or should i use something like: "東京に行きたいです。それは街が知りたいですから" I would like to know which one sounds more natural? Or is there another way to answer it, that sounds more natural?

Comment: I have edited this into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. I don't think there is a meaningful difference in English, either. ("I like anime so I want to go to Osaka." vs "I want to go to Osaka because I like anime.") If your reason part is long and spans several sentences, it would be better to present the conclusion first. In a short answer like this, however, it makes almost no difference.

By the way, when you present a reason after the conclusion, use からです, not ですから. それは should be omitted unless you have to emphasize something. If you wanted to say "metropolitan area", consider using 都会 instead of 街.

> 東京に行きたいです。都会の様子が知りたいからです。

Comment: Do japanese natives have any preference in that phrase usage?

Comment: @Nickzus Japanese subordinate clauses (もし～ば, から, ので, etc) must come before the main clause within one sentence, whereas English allows these to come before or after the main clause (e.g., "Do it *if you can*", "I was sleeping *when he returned*"). So if you want to say this in a single sentence, basically you have no option but to say the reason first. That said, you can always add a reason in the next sentence, like the example I gave.